# What are the examples of agents that is represent these characteristics?

Tags: machine-learning, intelligent-agent, multi-agent-systems

I'm looking for examples of AI systems or agents that best represent these five characteristics (one example for each characteristics):

- Reactivity
- Proactivity
- Adaptability
- Sociability
- Autonomy

It would be better if its machine learning-based application.

Comment: When you talk about agents in this context we tend to think of the formal definition of "[intelligent agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_agent)", which involves reflex (reactivity), utility, model-based, goal oriented, and learning (adaptability).  I would be interesting if there were formalizations for proactivity, sociability and autonomy!